# Script to copy documents from document libraries

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

I have a script for copying documents and their metadate from a source document library over to a destination document library. Whilst this is working correctly and the documents as well the majority of the metadata get correctly copied to the destination the problem I have is that:

1. The modified by column shows up the SharePoint security group instead of the actual user.
2. The checked out to column does not copy anything.

Is there anything I need to update on my script below to achieve this correctly? script snippet is shown below:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ea SilentlyContinue

$urlWebSrc = "https://testsite.info/sites/IT"
$listNameSrc = "Documents"
$urlWebTgt = "https://vine.info/dept/IT"
$listNameTgt = "Shared Documents"

$webSrc = Get-SPWeb $urlWebSrc
$webTgt = Get-SPWeb $urlWebTgt
$src = $webSrc.Lists[$listNameSrc]
$tgt = $webTgt.Lists[$listNameTgt]

$listItems = $src.Items
$listFolders = $src.Folders

$srcRootFolderUrl = ("{0}/{1}" -f $src.ParentWebUrl, $src)
$tgtRootFolderUrl = ("{0}/{1}" -f $tgt.ParentWebUrl, $tgt)

$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.Query = "<Where>
<BeginsWith>
<FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' />
<Value Type='ContentTypeId'>0x0101</Value>
</BeginsWith>
</Where>"

$rootItems = $src.GetItems($spQuery)

foreach ($rootItem in $rootItems) {
    $relative = $rootItem.Url
    $targetItem = $listItems | Where-Object { $_.Url -eq $relative }
    $sBytes = $targetItem.File.OpenBinary()
    $dFile = $tgt.RootFolder.Files.Add($targetItem.Name, $sBytes, $true)
    $dFile.Update()
    $dItem = $tgt.GetItems($spQuery) | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $targetItem.Name }
    $dItem["Modified"] = $rootItem["Modified"].ToLocalTime()
    $dItem["Created"] = $rootItem["Created"].ToLocalTime()
    $dItem["Author"] = $rootItem["Author"]
    $dItem["Editor"] = $rootItem["Editor"]

    $dItem["Committee"] = $rootItem["Committee"]
    $dItem["Dept"] = $rootItem["Dept"]
    $dItem["Organisation"] = $rootItem["Organisation"]
    $dItem["Checked Out To"] = $rootItem["Cheked Out To"]
    $dItem["Content Type"] = $rootItem["Content Type"]

    $ditem.Update()
    Write-Host "...... File Mirroring:" $dfile.Name "- Complete"
}

foreach ($folder in $listFolders) {
    $srcFolderUrl = $folder.Url
    $tgtFolderUrl = $srcFolderUrl
    $tgtFolderUrl = $tgtFolderUrl -replace $src, $tgt

    if (!($tgt.Folders | Where-Object { $_.Url -eq $tgtFolderURL })) {
        $srcParentFolderUrl = $folder.Folder.ParentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
        $tgtParentFolderUrl = $srcParentFolderURL -replace $srcRootFolderUrl,
        $tgtRootFolderUrl

        $newFolder = $tgt.Additem($tgtparentFolderURL,  
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, $folder.Name)
        $newFolder.SystemUpdate()
        Write-Host "Folder Creation:" $tgtFolderURL "- Complete"
    }

    $tgtFolder = $tgt.Folders | Where-Object { $_.Url -eq $tgtFolderURL }

    if ($folder.Folder.Files.Count -gt 0) {
        $spQuery.Folder = $folder.Folder
        $srcItems = $src.GetItems($spQuery)

        foreach ($item in $srcItems) {
            $relative = $item.Url
            $targetItem = $listItems | Where-Object { $_.Url -eq $relative }
            $sBytes = $targetItem.File.OpenBinary()
            $dFile = $tgtFolder.Folder.Files.Add($targetItem.Name, $sBytes, $true)
            $dFile.Update()
            $spQuery.Folder = $tgtFolder.Folder
            $dItem = $tgt.GetItems($spQuery) | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $targetItem.Name }
            $dItem["Modified"] = $item["Modified"].ToLocalTime()
            $dItem["Created"] = $item["Created"].ToLocalTime()
            $dItem["Author"] = $item["Author"]
            $dItem["Editor"] = $item["Editor"]

            $dItem["Committee"] = $rootItem["Committee"]
            $dItem["Dept"] = $rootItem["Dept"]
            $dItem["Organisation"] = $rootItem["Organisation"]
            $dItem["Checked Out To"] = $rootItem["Cheked Out To"]
            $dItem["Content Type"] = $rootItem["Content Type"]

            $dItem.Update()
            Write-Host "...... File Mirroring:" $dfile.Name "- Complete"
        }
    } 
}
```

So the bit that is not working correctly is the copying of the Modified By column where instead of copying the actual user it copies the sharepoint group where the user is in.

Also the Checked out to values are not being copied at all.

Any suggestions would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: Did you check that `$rootItem` held every information you need ? With `$rootItem | fl *` for example ? And you seem to have a big portion of the code re-used, maybe you could put that in a function ?